# Searching through arrays in Ruby using a range

Tags: ruby, arrays, search, numbers, range

i've seen a lot of other questions touch on the subject but nothing as on topic as to provide an answer for my particular problem. Is there a way to search an array and return values within a given range...
for clarity I have one array = [0,5,12]
I would like to compare array to another array (array2) using a range of numbers. 
Using array[0] as a starting point how would I return all values from array2 +/- 4 of array[0].

In this particular case the returned numbers from array2 will be within the range of -4 and 4.

Thanks for the help ninjas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a Range that is your target ±4 and then use [`Enumerable#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) (remember that Array includes Enumerable) and [`Range#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-include-3F).

For example, let us look for 11±4 in an array that contains the integers between 1 and 100 (inclusive):

```
a = (1..100).to_a
r = 11-4 .. 11+4
a.select { |i| r.include?(i) }
# [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

If you don't care about preserving order in your output and you don't have any duplicates in your array you could do it this way:

```
a & (c-w .. c+w).to_a
```

Where `c` is the center of your interval and `w` is the interval's width. Using [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-26) treats the arrays as sets so it will remove duplicates and is not guaranteed to preserver order.